# Checking Bitlocker Password

Tags: bitlocker, windows-server-2012-r2

Let us say I changed my Bitlocker password a couple of months ago, and I want to verify that the password that I have in my possession is actually the right password.

How can I verify it from Windows directly without resorting to restarting the machine, and entering the password?

One way of doing it is to click "Change Bitlocker password" and to enter the password that you think is correct in all 3 boxes (old password, new password, confirm new password). If the password is correct then it will say "successfully changed" and if the password is incorrect then it will say "please enter the correct current password"

However the disadvantage of this method is that it is registered by the computer as a password change, and I just want to verify.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any method to do this verification, however, you can display the recovery key and compare it to the one you have.

You can also take note of the recovery key so that you can restart the system in case you don't have the correct password.

Use this Powershell command (as administrator)

> (Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint C:).KeyProtector

and write down the "RecoveryPassword".

Comment: Thank you for this, and I am sure it will be useful for people searching for ways to display their recovery *key* but i was specifically looking for a way to verify the bitlocker *password*